# railsでcss適用させようとするとRack app error handling requestというのが出ます

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, css, scss

railsにcssを適用させたいのですが、適用されません

application.html.erb

```
    <title>UberEvaluation</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    a:visited { color:white; text-decoration:none }
    -->
</style>
</head>
```

application.css

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, or any plugin's
 * vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any other CSS/SCSS
 * files in this directory. Styles in this file should be added after the last require_* statement.
 * It is generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
body {
  background-color: red;
}
```

application.html.erbに `<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>` を記載すると出るエラー

```
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `silence' for #<Logger:0x0000561c9b2adcb8>>
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
2021-09-21 22:51:09 +0000: Rack app error handling request { GET /assets/application.self-d4834196f99ff2dc186095a72257a2665c6a77d7b9729fddbde938c08c63239f.css }
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `silence' for #<Logger:0x0000561c9b2adcb8>>
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:11:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:27:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/activesupport-5.2.6/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/actionpack-5.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:127:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-5.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:524:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/puma-3.12.6/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Answer (score 1):

`#<NoMethodError: undefined method 'silence' for #<Logger:0x0000561c9b2adcb8>>`
こちらがエラーの本体のようです。
`silence`や`logger.silence`でソースコードを検索してみて、その行を削除してみてはどうでしょうか。